# web scraping gives only first 4 elements on a page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrap the search result elements on this page: https://shop.bodybuilding.com/search?q=protein+bar&selected_tab=Products  with selenium but it gives me only the 4 first elements as a result.
I am not sure why? it is a javascript page? and how can I scrap all the elements on this search page?
here is the code I created :

```
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver')
url = 'https://shop.bodybuilding.com/search?q=protein+bar&selected_tab=Products'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
all_items = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'ProductTile ProductTile--flat Animate AnimateOnHover Animate--fade-in Animate--animated'})


for i in range(len(all_items)):
    prices=all_items[i].find('div', {'class': 'Price ProductTile__price'}).text
    names=all_items[i].find('p', {'class': 'ProductTile__title'}).text
    images=all_items[i].find('img')['src']
    url=all_items[i].find('a', {'class': 'Anchor ProductTile__image'})['href']

    print(images)
```

this is the result for the names on this page, as you see it only scrapes the first 4 elements !

```
BSN Protein Crisp Bars
Optimum Nutrition Protein Wafers
Herbaland Vegan Protein Gummies
Battle Bars Full Battle Rattle (FBR) Protein Bar
```

the same for prices, images, and URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to fix

You have to scroll, so all items will be loaded:

```
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(1)

    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
all_items = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'ProductTile ProductTile--flat Animate AnimateOnHover Animate--fade-in Animate--animated'})


for i in all_items:
    prices=i.find('div', {'class': 'Price ProductTile__price'}).text if i.find('div', {'class': 'Price ProductTile__price'}) else None
    names=i.find('p', {'class': 'ProductTile__title'}).text
    images=i.find('img')['src']
    url=i.find('a', {'class': 'Anchor ProductTile__image'})['href']

    print(images)
```

Comment: thank you so much, the problem is solved!