# Selenium only find few elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to make a recommendation system for webtoon, so I am collecting webtoon data. Currently, I wrote a code to scrap the url of the toons on the Kakao Webtoon page.

```py
def extract_from_page(page_link):
    links = []
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(page_link)
    
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".h-full.relative")
    for elem in elems:
        link = elem.get_attribute('href')
        if link:
            links.append({'id': int(link.split('/')[-1]), 'link': link})
    
    print(len(links))
    return links
```

This code works in weekly page(https://webtoon.kakao.com/original-webtoon, https://webtoon.kakao.com/original-novel)

However, in page that shows finished toons(https://webtoon.kakao.com/original-webtoon?tab=complete), it only receives 13 urls for the 13 webtoons at the top of the page.

I found similar post([web scraping gives only first 4 elements on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70411736/web-scraping-gives-only-first-4-elements-on-a-page)) and add scroll, but noting changed.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me the cause and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below.

```
driver.get("https://webtoon.kakao.com/original-webtoon?tab=complete")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

j = 1
for i in range(5):
    # Wait for the elements to load/appear
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'content')]")))
    # Get all the elements which contains href value
    links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@href,'content')]")
    # Iterate to print the links
    for link in links:
        print(f"{j} : {link.get_attribute('href')}")
        j += 1
    # Scroll to the last element of the list links
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",links[len(links)-1])
```

**Output:**

```
1 : https://webtoon.kakao.com/content/%EB%B0%A4%EC%9D%98-%ED%96%A5/1532
2 : https://webtoon.kakao.com/content/%EB%B8%8C%EB%A0%88%EC%9D%B4%EC%BB%A42/596
3 : https://webtoon.kakao.com/content/%ED%86%A0%EC%9D%B4-%EC%BD%A4%ED%94%8C%EB%A0%89%EC%8A%A4/1683
...
```

Comment: Thanks! it showed me what I wanted. As I scroll to the end of the screen, I declared the `links` variable before the for loop and upsize the range, then updated it while scrolling, and checked the links element outside loop.